# With Powershell, how do I populate a variable with the name of objects I get from Get-ChildItem?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-4.0, get-childitem

With Powershell, how do I populate a variable with the name of an object I get from `Get-ChildItem`?

Say, for example, I'm trying to get the names of OUs (so I can do input validation) under a given search base.

I can easily use a temp variable and do something like:

```
$ValidSites = Get-ChildItem -Path AD:\"OU=SomeOU,DC=contoso,DC=com" | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq "organizationalUnit" }
$ValidSiteNames = @("","","","","","","","","")

For ($i=0; $i -lt $ValidSites.Length; $i++) {

$ValidSiteNames[$i] = $ValidSites[$i].name

}
```

But, that's hacky and I end up with an extra variable I don't want or need (and, also extra effort and code).

I've tried piping to a `Select` statement (with `| Select $_.name`), but that's not giving me the expected results (just returns the same objects as if it wasn't there), so  I'm not sure what else to try.

How do I just the names of these objects returned by `Get-ChildItem` into an array without the extra effort and code involved in a temp variable and for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below line is working to create an array of names into $ValidSites.

```
$ValidSites = Get-ChildItem -Path AD:\"OU=SomeOU,DC=contoso,DC=com" | Where-Object { $_.ObjectClass -eq "organizationalUnit" } | select -expand name
```